# Endless loading screen in Siverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, progress

Upon Compiling and Running, when I try to load the page in either Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox it just shows the blue progress thing rotating in circles, and for a split second it will show a percentage and then that disappears

Code for entire LoginPage

```
public partial class LoginPage : UserControl
    {
        public bool UsernameExists = false;
        public bool PasswordExists = false;
        public bool SchoolExists = false;
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void username_autocompletebox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Checks if user entered all neccessary values, enables Login_button if so
            if (username_autocompletebox.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                UsernameExists = true;
            }
            else
            {
                UsernameExists = false;
            }
            if (UsernameExists = true && PasswordExists == true && SchoolExists == true)
            {
                Login_button.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Login_button.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void password_passwordbox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Checks if user entered all neccessary values, enables Login_button if so
            if (password_passwordbox.Password.Length != 0)
            {
                PasswordExists = true;
            }
            else
            {
                PasswordExists = false;
            }
            if (UsernameExists = true && PasswordExists == true && SchoolExists == true)
            {
                Login_button.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Login_button.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void school_combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Checks if user entered all neccessary values, enables Login_button if so
            if (school_combobox.SelectedItem != null && school_combobox.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Select a School")
            {
                SchoolExists = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SchoolExists = false;
            }
            if (UsernameExists = true && PasswordExists == true && SchoolExists == true)
            {
                Login_button.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Login_button.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void Login_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Authenticate Authenticator = new Authenticate();
            User CurrentUser = Authenticator.Login(username_autocompletebox.Text, password_passwordbox.Password, school_combobox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely an unhandled exception being handled in `Application_UnHandledException`. Place a breakpoint at your `Application_UnHandledException` handler to see the problem, or in VS [turn on the notification](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/04/03/customizing-exception-handling-in-the-vs-debugger.aspx) of unhandled exceptions when they are thrown. You could also locate the stacktrace in the browser to see the problem. This typically occurs when the XAML is incorrect somewhere. Referencing event handlers which may not exist, or styles, etc...